# Obtaining a Pool ID to deploy OpenShift Origin

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-origin

I'm trying to automate the deployment of OpenShift Origin into AWS, because it's a dependency of another product which I also need to deploy on demand. There are various solutions for this, but they all require a Pool ID at some point in the process. What is a Pool ID? I realise it's associated with a Redhat subscription, but can I script the generation of a Pool ID? And if so, is it necessary to treat it as a secret?

Comment: If you are using OpenShift Origin (and not OpenShift Container Platform), then subscriptions should not apply. Origin is the free Open Source upstream version and you don't need subscriptions to use it.

Comment: All the installation instructions that I have found for OpenShift require the provision of a Pool ID, and none appear to be optional.

Comment: Even this one, which is the installation instructions for OpenShift Origin? https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html I still think you are finding the OpenShift Container Platform instructions and not Origin.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the subscriptions available pool with :

```
subscription-manager list --available --pool-only
```

If you are many subscription, you can filter the result with --matches option (filter can contain regex)  :

```
  --matches=FILTER_STRING
                    lists only subscriptions or products containing the
                    specified expression in the subscription or product
                    information, varying with the list requested and the
                    server version (case-insensitive).
```

Comment: I'm in the process of setting up `subscription-manager`, but it looks like you're assuming we already have a subscription? Is it one pool ID per subscription? Can a subscription have a pool of pool IDs?

Comment: you need to register first before adding a subscription

`subscription-manager register`

and then you can attach a subscription. Each subscription has a unique Pool ID so, I don't think a subscription can have a pool of pool IDs.